# Read a field from every array object

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON file that returns this :

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "",
  "lastName": "",
  "birthDate": "",
  "invoice": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "date": "20/10/2015"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "date": "20/8/2013"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "date": "20/6/2012"
    }
  ]
}
```

if I access `invoice[0].date` I will get `"20/10/2015"`.

I need to save in an array all three dates in this case, so that I can show it in a dropdown. `<select>` option should have all three dates.

How do I save and access those in JavaScript?

```
var allDates=data.info[all arrays].date // date field of every object
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Can you include the `JSON` at Question?

Comment: I edited it. I removed a few fields to simplify the idea

Comment: @MonnIca Have you tried code at Answer?

Comment: Just did ! Thank you!!

Comment: You JSON was still not valid, so I edited it and corrected it according to a few assumptions.

Comment: Oh I didn't notice. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use `Array.map()` for this - it executes a function against every element of an array and makes a new array from the results. So you can do this:

```
function toDate( item ) {
   return item.date;
}
var allDates = info.map( toDate );
```

Comment: Thank you soo much!!! This is just what I needed!

Comment: No problem - good luck with your project!